# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while applying onPage filters

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, listview

It seems to be very basic issue but not able to resolve it. I have listview control & some filters as radiobuttonlist. Now when page loads it shows data correctly. But when I try to apply filters on it it shows exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". And also please suggest if any simplified method can be applied on filters to reduce my current coding length.

vb codePreRender event

```
Private Sub chemists_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    Try
        Dim citySelector As DropDownList = Page.Master.FindControl("locationSelector")
        If Session("masterLocation") Is Nothing Then
            citySelector.Text = "Pune"
        Else
            citySelector.Text = Session("masterLocation").ToString()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try

    Me.PopulateAreas()

    Try
        If Not Session("Data") Is Nothing Then
            chemists.DataSource = Session("Data")
            chemists.DataBind()
        Else
            Dim citySelector As DropDownList = Page.Master.FindControl("locationSelector")
            query = "SELECT chemistID, name, address, thumbnail, slot1From, slot1To, products FROM chemists where city like '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and status = 'active'"
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim table As New DataTable
            da.Fill(table)
            ViewState("Data") = table
            chemists.DataSource = table
            chemists.DataBind()
        End If

        'mainCount.Text = table.Rows(0)("countRows").ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here I have used prerender event because I have dropdownlist in master page & I m getting it's control from master page. Till here all works fine.

Problem comes here when I try to apply on page filters in it. following is code

```
Private Sub areasList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles areasList.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim citySelector As DropDownList = Page.Master.FindControl("locationSelector")
    locationFilter.Text = areasList.SelectedItem.ToString
    city.Text = citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString
    area.Text = areasList.SelectedIndex.ToString
    Try
        Session("Data") = Nothing
        If areasList.SelectedValue <> "All" And productList.SelectedValue <> "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue <> "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM chemists where address Like '%" + areasList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and products Like '%" + productList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and payment Like '%" + paymentsList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and city = '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "' and status = 'active' "

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue = "All" And productList.SelectedValue <> "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue.ToString <> "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM chemists where products Like '%" + productList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and payment Like '%" + paymentsList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and city = '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "' and status = 'active'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue = "All" And productList.SelectedValue = "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue.ToString <> "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM chemists WHERE payment Like '%" + paymentsList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and city = '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "' and status = 'active'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue <> "All" And productList.SelectedValue = "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue.ToString = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM chemists WHERE address Like '%" + areasList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and city = '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "' and status = 'active'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue <> "All" And productList.SelectedValue <> "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue.ToString = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM chemists WHERE address Like '%" + areasList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and products Like '%" + productList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and city = '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "' and status = 'active'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue = "All" And productList.SelectedValue <> "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue.ToString = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM chemists WHERE products Like '%" + productList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and city = '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "' and status = 'active'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue = "All" And productList.SelectedValue = "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM chemists where city = '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "' and status = 'active'"
        End If

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable

        da.Fill(table)
        Session("Data") = table
        chemists.DataSource = table
        chemists.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What mechanism do you have to debug it?

Comment: @Drew I have put breakpoint on selectedIndexChanged of filters & after passing it through query it shows Nothing in query variable. So probably query is not executing

Comment: Some times all we can really help with is Rubber Duck debugging :p

Comment: @Drew I have checked line by line putting breakpoint. after Hitting it to relative query it's not binding listview & throws exception hence query goes nothing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked code and found that `productList` dropdown bounded property, but for somehow it didn't maintain selected index.

So please try as below,

```
productList.SelectedIndex = 0
```

This will solve issue.